# How to leave an auto-updating timestamp alone when performing an UPDATE

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-update

Consider a very simple table:

```
create table test (
  data varchar(2048),
  modified timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) engine=InnoDB;
```

We insert some rows:

```
insert into test (data) values (
  ('some data'),
  ('some other data'),
  ('etc...')
);
```

Now normally, we want the timestamps on these rows to automatically update. The owner of `some data` might touch their row:

```
update test set data='some different data' where data='some other data';
```

The `modified` stamp will be updated as expected and desired. But, suppose an admin realizes some of these rows are wrong -- the script updating the data has been inserting '**TEST**' for the last hour (or whatever). So, we need to change the data without updating the timestamps -- because the timestamps aren't intended to represent administrative cleanup.

---

Can this update be modified to leave the timestamp alone?

```
update test set data = replace(data, '__TEST__', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the timestamp to itself:

```
update test set data = replace(data, '__TEST__', ''), modified = modified;
```